# setState doesnt render extra one time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Code A:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.dateString = this.props.navigation.getParam('dateString', moment());
}
```

Code B:

```
state = { dateString: moment() }

componentDidMount(){
  const dateString = this.props.navigation.getParam('dateString', moment());

  this.setState({ dateString })
}
```

`dateString` is a parameter passed from previous screen. I've `console.log` in `render()` and found that they appeared to be exactly the same number of times? I was expecting Code B to render one extra time since it uses `setState`?

Which way of above is a better approach?

Comment: having data as properties in your class is the worst approach, if you update the property, your component will never rerender

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case in this your specific case, but: React may batch multiple setState calls together. So even if you have multiple async setState calls, there might only one (re-)render. So you shouldn’t rely on the number of calls to render

Comment: I'm not relying on number of calls to render, just trying to figure which way is more optimal

Comment: Yeah, didn’t mean to imply you do rely on it, was just a side note. Regarding what is better: it depends on whether you need the dateString in the state (e.g. because you change it with this.setState over time and want your component to rerender) or if it’s only set once.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `this.props.navigation.getParam('dateString', moment())` in `render` and `componentDidmount()`.

If both values are same it wont trigger a re-render as react re-render the components only if state change there if you made it `PureComponent`.

In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nithuan141/ymedpngk/1/) you can try running the code by changing Pure and normal component and can see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put in the Code B the state inside constructor() method like this:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { dateString: moment() }
}
```

I don't usually use to put state floating in the class, I always put him in the constructor.